# Summing values in a group of a groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum up the values of a column in a groupby object for each of entries by which I grouped.

Say I had a df like this:

```
Letters Numbers Items Bool
A       1       lamp  1
B       2       glass 1
B       2       table 1
C       5       pic   0
```

And I groupby letters and then want to know the sum of the bools in the letters group. How would I do this? I've been trying

```
df_new = df.groupby('letters').bool.sum()
```

...

```
df_new = df.groupby('letters').sum('bool')
```

and other variations...

In the end I would like to get a vector that contains a value for the sum of each of the letters' groups. For the ex., it would be `[1,2,0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close!  Given

```
>>> df
  Letters  Numbers  Items  Bool
0       A        1   lamp     1
1       B        2  glass     1
2       B        2  table     1
3       C        5    pic     0
```

You could sum everything and take the column you want:

```
>>> # slower
>>> df.groupby("Letters").sum()["Bool"] # sum everything, select Bool
Letters
A          1
B          2
C          0
Name: Bool, dtype: int64
```

Or better, take only the column you want and sum it:

```
>>> df.groupby("Letters")["Bool"].sum() # select Bool, sum it
Letters
A          1
B          2
C          0
Name: Bool, dtype: int64
```

I prefer to stick with the `Series`, because you can do more with it, but you can convert this to a `list` using `list` or `.tolist()` if you prefer.

Comment: @mgilson: I think I may have mentioned this once here before, but I used to have a homegrown code I hacked together to do data munging. After an afternoon with `pandas` I tossed it and haven't looked back.  My only hope is that Martijn never takes it up :^) -- the first time I see him answering a `pandas` question I'm switching to Ruby or Julia or something.  <0.5 wink>

Comment: I don't think Martijn's even picked up numpy/scipy yet.  I don't think he's interested.  To be fair, I'm slowly trying to learn ruby because our product uses it.  Thus far, I'm mostly not impressed (Though it does have  a few interesting bits like their "blocks" or whatever they call them)... I'm also interested in learning Go...